# Debian: environment variable not available for script running from cron?

Tags: debian, cron

I have this line:

```
echo $(date '+%Y %b %d %H:%m') Your output $HOSTNAME
```

When I do it manually from command line I can see my $HOSTNAME just fine.

However, when it's running from a script that's run by a cron job (root) the $HOSTNAME is always empty.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$HOSTNAME` is set by some shells (like bash), it is not an environment variable

Set your shell script to run under bash (put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line instead of `#!/bin/sh`) and try again